# Transfer file to certain location , USB to be exact

Tags: vb.net, file-transfer

The question is,  I want to do file transferring using VB

1- I already have drag and drop window which is user drag n drop their file over that window..and it depend to user whether to transfer the file to the USB drive or not..can it be done ?

2 - here my code for drag n drop window..

```
Private Sub ListBox4_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
                                  Handles ListBox4.DragEnter
        If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
        Else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub ListBox4_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
                              Handles ListBox4.DragDrop
    Dim s() As String = e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", False)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 1
        ListBox4.Items.Add(s(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

3 - So what i want to do is,whatever file been dropping over there can be transfer to USB...with user click "Transfer"

Comment: "transfer the file to the USB drive" - hum.. *WHICH* USB drive?

Comment: any..like user insert a pendrive to their laptop..

Comment: And if the user inserts 5 drives?

Comment: make sense ...haha..i didnt think about it still... I just to show up some Proof of concept that it can be done. So one drive is enough..or maybe user can select the drive ? thx dude..

Comment: Check out the `System.IO.DriveInfo` class and the rest of the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: Alright, will study on those class..thx :)

Comment: is it the same way if I want user to choose manually the drive that they want to transfer it ? just like browsing a folder popup .. but this one user select the folder..?